# Provisioning profile expiration date includes or excludes the end day?

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile

So, I have a provisioning profile expiring on the 02/04/2018.
It means that my app will expire on the 02/04/2018 00:00 (excluded) or on the 03/04/2018 00:00 (included) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that the app will expire on the 02/04/2018 00:00 (excluded) , 1 second after 01/04/2018 12:00 PM you can't test the app with pp